# When giving a property as variable in description of @RequestBody annotation it is not showing the actual value of the property

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I have a spring boot project. When I try to add `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody` annotation to a request body in a controller like this:
`@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(description = "${somepropertyname.somesubpropertyname.value}"`
instead of displaying the value of the property it just displays the property as it is on the ui.
Where as for other annotation like `@Paramter`, `@Schema`, `@Operation` etc it is giving the desired result.

Any help here is appreciated.
PS: I am using Spring Boot 3.1.1 and Java 17
Using swagger via spring-doc
Swagger-UI version: 4.18.2
Swagger/OpenAPI version: OpenAPI 3.0

I tried using only `@Parameter` but then the description is not at all visible.